# Django Template Variable not found

Tags: python, django, templates, variables

I'm pretty new to Django and I'm really struggling with this issue. So if anyone can help I would be very grateful :).
Basically everytime I access the path to reach one specific profile, the variable {{profile.user.username|default="Not found"}} does not get recognised and the default value is the output. When I access another path like profile_list, the right output comes up from the same variable.
Both html pages(profile.html and profile_list.html) inherit from base.html. Any idea where the issue might be or where I should be looking into?

**profile.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div class="column">
<div class="block">
<h1 class="title is-1">
    {{profile.user.username|default:"Not found"}}
</h1>
</div>
</div>
{%endblock content%}
```

**profile_list.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<div class="column">

{% for profile in profiles %}

<div class="block">
  <div class="card">
    <a href="#">
      <div class="card-content">
        <div class="media">
          <div class="media-left">
            <figure class="image is-48x48">
              <img src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/96x96.png"
                   alt="Placeholder image">
            </figure>
          </div>
          <div class="media-content">
            <p class="title is-4">
              {{ profile.user.username }}
            </p>
            <p class="subtitle is-6">
              @{{ profile.user.username|lower }}
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

{% endfor %}

</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Profile

# Create your views here.
def dashboard(request):
return render(request, 'base.html')

def profile_list(request):
 profile = Profile.objects.exclude(user=request.user)
 return render(request, 'myapp/profile_list.html',   {'profiles':profiles})

def profile(request, pk):
    profile = Profile.objects.get(pk=pk),
    return render(request, 'myapp/profile.html', {'profile':profile})
```

```
**urls.py**
from django.urls import path
from .views import dashboard, profile_list, profile
app_name = 'myapp'

urlpatterns = [
path("", dashboard, name='dashboard'),
path("profile_list/", profile_list, name="profile_list"),
path("profile/<int:pk>", profile, name="profile")]
```

Comment: There is a typo in views->profile_list: "profiles = " missing the "s". Please check again the post because like that profile_list can not display any profile

Comment: Can you add your profile urls.py please.

Comment: @raphael added it. Thank you for looking over it :)

Comment: @Razenstein Hi, thank you for looking over it. Actually the /profile_list has the right output with all the list of profiles. When I try to access specific profiles for eg: /profile/1 it will not give me the variable as an ouput.

Comment: just check in the view if profile is empty with print(profile) before the call to render